# Android PopupMenu opening on wrong positions

Tags: android, listview, popup, position

I have a listView where each item has a button that opens a PopupMenu with options.

Most of the time, these menus open at wrong positions (sometimes they open on correct positions), these random opens are not even consistent.

[image]

[image]

**Choosing an option in the Menu does manipulate with the correct item on the position I originally tried to open the Menu**

My code:

```
settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, settings);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notes_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    String itemTitle = item.getTitle().toString();

                    switch (itemTitle) {

                        case "Add Pictures": 

                            //adding pictures

                        case "Delete":

                            //deleting

                        case "Share":

                            //sharing

                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show(); 


        }
    });
```

This `settings` button is located inside the `public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method of my listView adapter.

Any help is greatly appreciated! ^^

Comment: Did you try creating the popup before the onclick listener and only calling popup.show()  in the onClickListener of settings button?

Comment: @Tushar, No I have not, and it did do the trick! Thank you very much :) Any possible explanation as to why it was happening ?

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answer I've written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the popup before setting the onClickListener and only call popup.show() inside onClick().

Comment: Thanks for the Solution Tushar!